# Javadoc for javadoc com.install4j.runtime.beans.formcomponents.DirectoryChooserComponent

Tags: install4j

I want to set starting directory for DirectoryChooserComponent in my initialization script but I don't see the javadoc for this anywhere.

Should I not access this component directly?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: DON'T DO THAT.

Instead, use setVariable action to set a variable earlier and then use that in the field for initial directory in the UI.